# Images next to the icons in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how can I move the text next to the little images. As you can see it in the image, the text and icons are not completely in-line with each other.

[image]

```css
h1.titu{
    margin-left: 370px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 1px
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 7vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url(../images/lines.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:
    transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.socialmedia {
    margin-left: 400px;
}

img.eye{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 240px;
}

img.instagram{
    padding-left: 190px;
}

img.twitter{
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="../CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id ="contact">
  
<h1 class="titu">contact</h1>
    
</body>
<div class="socialmedia">
<p >  
<img class="insta" src="../images/insta.png" width="60"> 
    
    Juliancmr
</p>   
     
 <p>  
<img class="twitter"src="../images/twitter.png" width="60">
     Julian Mancera
</p>     
     
    
<p>  
<img class="twitter"src="../images/in.png" width="60">
    Julian.mr mancera
</p> 

    
<p>  
<img class="mail" src="../images/mail.png" width="60">
    
    Julian.mr@hotmail.com
</p> 
    </div>

</html>
```

Comment: In addition to other people editing, I've fixed the formatting so the snippet is functional. Please adjust your code so that it demonstrates the problem which you are experiencing. Given that you have an image in your HTML, I'd suggest adding that image to your question, then using the link to `i.stack.imgur.com` in your HTML/CSS as a way to have the snippet show what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Using vertical-align on images you can tweek it's position like this

```
.socialmedia img{
   vertical-align:-10px;
}
```

Tweak the -10px up or down to your liking

Answer (score 0):

If you put the images and text in a div that has display: flex on it, it will align things center. Something like:

```
<div class="flex-row">
     <img src="image-src.jpg">
     <p>caption<p>
     <img src="image-src.jpg">
     <p>caption<p>
</div>
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/02sgLq1n/2/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `body` tag in the given html is prematurely closed (it's before the div, it should be at the end of the body content, i.e. before the `</html>` tag). Also, as mentioned in a previous answer, the body tag does not take an id, it is a native tag and can be referred to as `body{}` in css.

As for the matter of positioning the icons, I too would recommend [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), although given that you are a beginner, it may be running before you can walk. I have linked to an article that is a good read if you want to use this.

You are using quite a few classes as-is to style your icons. If you want your icons to have similar height/width/position, I would recommend using **one**  icon class, and setting the img src in the HTML.

Sample snippet using [flex](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/vn4ebaho/):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.icon {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class='flex-row'>
    <img class='icon' src=" " alt="Insta icon">
    <p>Instagram</p>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-row'>
    <img class='icon' src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1051/1051280.svg" alt="Twitter icon">
    <p>Julian.mr mancera</p>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-row'>
    <img class='icon' src=" " alt="LkedIn icon">
    <p>LinkedIn</p>
  </div>
  <div class='flex-row'>
    <img class='icon' src=" " alt="Email icon">
    <p>E-mail</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR you could use `display:inline-block` with  `vertical-align:middle` to align your img/paragraphs as follows:  ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/mhz85by3/))

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.socialmed {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}

.smtext {
  color: red;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  font-size:10pt;
}

.icon {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.icon, .smtext {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class='socialmed'>
    <img class='icon' src=" " alt="Insta icon">
    <p class='smtext'>Instagram</p>
  </div>
  <div class='socialmed'>
    <img class='icon' src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1051/1051280.svg" alt="Twitter icon">
    <p class='smtext'>Julian.mr mancera</p>
  </div>
  <div class='socialmed'>
    <img class='icon' src=" " alt="LkedIn icon">
    <p class='smtext'>LinkedIn</p>
  </div>
  <div class='socialmed'>
    <img class='icon' src=" " alt="Email icon">
    <p class='smtext'>E-mail</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!